# I am upgrading Apache superset from 0.36.0 to 1.0.0 , after upgrading it i am facing error , i am using an external database

Tags: docker, apache-superset, k3s

**I am upgrading Apache superset from 0.36.0 to 1.0.0 , on k3s Kubernetes cluster after upgrading it i am facing error specified below . I am using an external postgresql database to connect to superset . Can someone please tell me what could be the issue and how to migrate the old dashboard and every thing to new upgraded version  .**

I am using these specs in docker file

```
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
redis==3.5.3
flower==0.9.7
pybigquery==0.5.0
pymysql==1.0.2
mysqlclient==2.0.3
apache-superset==1.0.1
gunicorn[gevent]==20.0.4
Werkzeug==0.16.0
Pillow==2.2.2
```

Stacktrace

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column dashboards.uuid does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT dashboards.uuid AS dashboards_uuid, dashboards.create...
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "dashboards.id".


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/decorators.py", line 109, in wraps
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/superset/utils/log.py", line 162, in wrapper
    value = f(*args, add_extra_log_payload=log, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/superset/views/core.py", line 1803, in dashboard
    dash = qry.one_or_none()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3459, in one_or_none
    ret = list(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3535, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3560, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1124, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column dashboards.uuid does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT dashboards.uuid AS dashboards_uuid, dashboards.create...
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "dashboards.id".

[SQL: SELECT dashboards.uuid AS dashboards_uuid, dashboards.created_on AS dashboards_created_on, dashboards.changed_on AS dashboards_changed_on, dashboards.id AS dashboards_id, dashboards.dashboard_title AS dashboards_dashboard_title, dashboards.position_json AS dashboards_position_json, dashboards.description AS dashboards_description, dashboards.css AS dashboards_css, dashboards.json_metadata AS dashboards_json_metadata, dashboards.slug AS dashboards_slug, dashboards.published AS dashboards_published, dashboards.created_by_fk AS dashboards_created_by_fk, dashboards.changed_by_fk AS dashboards_changed_by_fk 
FROM dashboards 
WHERE dashboards.id = %(id_1)s]
[parameters: {'id_1': 1}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

Comment: Did you run `superset db upgrade`? There's a DB migration that needs to run to add the UUID column.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Guys `superset db downgrade and superset db upgrade` worked

Comment: There is no need to say thank you as an answer. It is enough to upvote and/or mark the correct answer as accepted. If you want to add something helpful use the edit function on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might not have run the database migrations as part of the upgrade.

`superset db upgrade` is the command, more information here:
https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/upgrading-superset

Comment: I noticed that when the uuid migration script was optimized we added a try/except block that might make the migration succeed without the column being created. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running:

```
superset db downgrade 18532d70ab98
superset db upgrade b56500de1855
```

This should re-run the UUID database migration. Check if dashboards.uuid exists, and then run:

```
superset db upgrade
```